# What's up with Facebook Pages why is there fragmentation

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to figure out why Facebook is creating fragmentation with its pages. I really don't understand it. Also is there anything that can be done about this.

Here is a perfect example I have my Facebook company page for "Scoreoid" (http://www.facebook.com/pages/Scoreoid/245182948843019) this has my content wall post's, photos ect..

Then I have this page which I guess is only connected to the Scoreoid website which is new and was automatically done http://www.facebook.com/pages/Scoreoid-the-ultimate-game-platform-for-developers/269861406410210

This is the page for the Scoreoid site which has 130 likes but of course on Facebook it only shows 15 another question either way why is there two pages why can't everything be connected to one page.

All this does is create fragmentation which is noting but bad user experiences.

It would max sense to have everything directed to the Facebook main page. Of course I have other questions for which do I run advertising on which should I update with content?

Answer (score 2):

I've already answered you here two weeks ago:

[Facebook Likes not showing on Facebook page but show up on site](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9066640/facebook-likes-not-showing-on-facebook-page-but-show-up-on-site)

Facebook pages like counts are **NOT THE SAME** as like counts for a web site.  They **cannot** be joined by Facebook as they are two separate IDs.  You can have your parsing scripts add together the two like counts yourself.

Comment: That's for likes but are there two different Facebook pages their is no point in that, I understand the likes as Facebook wants to have a different count but content should only be on one page

Comment: You never accepted the other answer so I assumed that you were asking the same thing again in a new question (regarding a like of a web page vs a like of a facebook page).  The answer still applies for two separate facebook pages too.  Two different id's, two different counts.  You will need to add them together yourself.  Facebook didn't fragment anything.

Answer (score 0):

This has been my experience. If you add the open graph meta tags (og:url, og:image, og:type, etc.) Facebook will create a "facebook page", but this page will only be accessable by you. This is the message that facebook will show on this open graph page: http://snag.gy/z9UfG.jpg

If besides this you create another page then it will not be linked with this page. I recommend you use the page you created as that page is accessible by everyone.

If this is not your case then please clarify.

Comment: Thanks @derickito if I understand correctly what I publish on this page IE on this page's wall it will be sent to the users that liked the site only. 

Either way I need to publish content twice once two the main facebook page and again to the page that is connected to the site url.

Also the likes are off but I guess that's just Facebook

Comment: Yes to publishing to your likes. See this URL so that you know what I'm talking about: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#publishing One way that you could unite the 2 is put the URL of your facebook page on your like button. This way when people like your webpage they will really be liking your facebook page.